# Vector folding using Divide et Impera in c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, vector, folding

I'm in trouble on a College project.The project needs to be done using c# as a programming language and made in Windows Form like.
The program executes. I know it has flaws but at least i want to know how to get of this error: http://postimg.org/image/gwuzmyc73/ .
For the problem i need to fold a vector using the Divide et Impera.
I need to insert a number from the keyboard n, the generated vector would be like a=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and the final elements are 1,3,5,7.
The problem sounds like:
A vector of n elements.We define its folding by overlaping the 2 halfs,if n is odd.The 2 halfs are folded  again until de subvector reaches 1 element.Utilize Divide et Impera.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Plierea_Vectorilor
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int n;
    public int i;
    public int[] efinal = new int[50];
    public string m = new string(new char[50]);
    public int Ls, Ld;
    public char[] aux = new char[50];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Pliaza(int p,int q)
    {
        if (p == q)
       {
            efinal[p] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((q - p + 1) % 2 != 0)
            {
                Ls = (p + q) / 2 - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Ls = (p + q) / 2;
            }
            Ld = (p + q) / 2 + 1;

        }


        Pliaza(p, Ls);
        Pliaza(Ld, q);
        /*
        string ss = Ls.ToString();
        string sd = Ld.ToString();


         for (i = p; i <= Ls; i++)
         {

             aux[0] = 'S';
             string.Concat(aux, ss);
             string.Concat(aux, " ");
             string m = aux.ToString();
             string.Concat(aux, m[i]);

         }


          for ( i = Ld; i <= q; i++)
           {
               aux[0] = 'D';
               string.Concat(aux,Ld);
               string.Concat(aux, " ");
               string m = aux.ToString(); 
               string.Concat(aux, m[i]); 


           }
          */


    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pliaza(1, n);
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (efinal[i]!=0)
            {
                label2.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
            }
        }


    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ALWAYS executing the Pliaza function FROM Pliaza. Aren't you missing a finish condition?

The recursive loop must be finished sometime in someway, else you will get that stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

A `StackOverflowException` usually means you have uncontrolled recursion going on. Reviewing your code, I see that `Pliaza` calls itself twice, using different variables ... but there is **no** path for `Pliaza` to exit **without** calling itself. You need some path to let the recursion bottom out.  Very likely this would be to add a `return;` statement after the `efinal[p] = 1;` line.

Comment: 'Plierea_Vectorilor.Form1.Pliaza(int, int)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: That's silly -- it's a void, why should it return a value?

Comment: I changed "public void Pliaza" into "public int Pliaza" and i get that error.i'm not that dumb...I tried to put in a comment the first "if" but i see that i get the same error,and i guess the problem is not there.